# How to draw a cone with given height and radius

Tags: matlab

I have to draw a cone with a given height and radius at a specific co-ordinate.

MATLAB has the function `cylinder(r)`, but it draws only a unit cylinder whereas I need it to be of a specific height.

None of the other links specify how to draw a cone of height 'h'.

Comment: So do you want to draw a cylinder or a cone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab's [`cylinder`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cylinder.html) can be used to draw cones by specifying a radius that decreases to 0. And height is just a `z` scaling factor. (Radius could also be realized as an `x`,`y` scaling factor, but the `cylinder` function permits directly specifying the radius values so that's not needed).

```
R = 1; %// radius
H = 3; %// height
N = 100; %// number of points to define the circumference
[x, y, z] = cylinder([0 R], N);
mesh(x, y, H*z)
```

[image]

Comment: You should also rephrase your question: is it a _cone_ or a _cylinder_ you want?

Comment: I want a cone. Basically the scaling factor is what I was unable to think of.

Answer (score 0):

A cylinder at `[x y z]` with height `h`, radius `r`,

```
x = 10;
y = 20;
z = 5;
h = 10;
r = 1;
[X,Y,Z] = cylinder(r,30);
X = X + x;
Y = Y + y;
Z = Z*h + z;
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]